# Has TinyMCE JQuery Package better browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, cross-browser

I'm wondering if the JQuery version of TinyMCE has less browser compatibility issues, thanks to JQuery.

Comment: I doubt it since the only thing the jquery version does is apply it. The core of TinyMCE is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the compatibility is the same. But i strongly adise you not to use the jQuery tinymce build. It is slower than the regular tinymce build probably due to the jquery object creation overhead.